# VSCODE with jupyter notebook: output of externally executed programs (like coin-or/pulp) are not shown in output or terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, message, pulp, coin-or

If I run test1.py (copied from https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/examples/test1.py) then I get some information directly form the solver (GLPK) as output in the terminal.

If I copy the script into a notebook file, then this output is not visible. How can I setup VSCcode to show those messages?

Remark: If I run the notebook from jupyter lab then the output is shown in the anaconda prompt.

Why is this important: the runtime of (Mixed-Integer) Linear Programming Solver could be quite long. The messages show the solution progress.

This is the output which I am missing when running the notebook.

`3 rows, 3 columns, 6 non-zeros
11 lines were read
GLPK Simplex Optimizer 5.0
3 rows, 3 columns, 6 non-zeros
Preprocessing...
1 row, 2 columns, 2 non-zeros
Scaling...
A: min|aij| =  1.000e+00  max|aij| =  1.000e+00  ratio =  1.000e+00
Problem data seem to be well scaled
Constructing initial basis...
Size of triangular part is 1
0: obj =   5.000000000e+01 inf =   4.000e+00 (1)
1: obj =   5.400000000e+01 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)

- ```
  2: obj =   5.400000000e+01 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
  ```

OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND
Time used:   0.0 secs
Memory used: 0.0 Mb (40400 bytes)
Writing basic solution to 'C:\Users\JB221\AppData\Local\Temp\ed788d9e18ef4b91985c4e7931e700f9-pulp.sol'...`